# React Fizz-Buzz

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I have been having an issue with my Fizz-Buzz app. The console output seems to be ok but the display always increments the console number. The outputs are as follows:

Console: 1 /
Display: 2 /
Text: /
Display Text:

Console: 2 /
Display: 3 /
Text:  /
Display Text:

Console: 3 /
Display: 4 /
Text: Fizz /
Display Text: Fizz

The code:

```js
class FizzBuzz extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      number: 1,
      fizzbuzz: ""
    }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
    this.fizzOrBuzz = this.fizzOrBuzz.bind(this)
  }

  onClick() {
    let tempNo = this.state.number + 1
    this.setState({ number: tempNo })
    console.log(this.state.number)
    this.fizzOrBuzz()
  }

  fizzOrBuzz() {
    if ((this.state.number % 3 === 0) && (this.state.number % 5 === 0)) {
      console.log("fizz buzz")
      this.setState({ fizzbuzz: "Fizz-Buzz" })
    } else if (this.state.number % 3 === 0) {
      console.log("fizz")
      this.setState({ fizzbuzz: "Fizz" })
    } else if (this.state.number % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("buzz")
      this.setState({ fizzbuzz: "Buzz" })
    } else {
      this.setState({ fizzbuzz: "" })
    }
    console.log(this.state.number)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Number: {this.state.number}</p>
        <h2>{this.state.fizzbuzz}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Next</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FizzBuzz
```

How can I get the page to render the same number as the console?

Comment: `this.setState()` is asynchronous - the actual change to the state is not reflected in `this.state` before you reach `this.fizzOrBuzz()`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in the comment, `this.setState()` is asynchronous, and you'd have to call `this.fizzOrBuzz()` as its callback.

However, as the fizziness or buzziness of a number is always derivable from the number itself, it should not be in the state at all.

```
function fizzOrBuzz(number) {
  if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0) {
    return "Fizz-Buzz";
  } else if (number % 3 === 0) {
    return "Fizz";
  } else if (number % 5 === 0) {
    return "Buzz";
  }
  return "";
}

class FizzBuzz extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: 1,
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Number: {this.state.number}</p>
        <h2>{fizzOrBuzz(this.state.number)}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting state and calling fizzbuzz which uses the state would not work as the state may or may not have been updated. You should put fizzbuzz as the callback to ensure the state is already updated before using it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate